# Load url for getJSON based on select option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm new to jquery and I want **to load url to getJSON function based on the selected option**, then load the json data into a table .The json files are in a folder /json 
For instance: if I choose clerk in the select option menu I want the url to be "json/clerk.json".

 This code is not correct, but the getJson is ok only the variable url remains null, which is the variable scope problem.
 Basically Here's jquery have tried so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var url = null; //url for the getJson function
  function employeeType()
    {
      $('#user').change(function() {
        /* setting currently changed option value to option variable */
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        console.log(option);
        switch (option) {
          case "accountant":
            url = "json/accountant.json";
            return url;
            break;
          case "clerk":
            url = "json/clerk.json";
            return url;
            break;
          case "admin":
            url = "json/administration.json";
            return url;
            break;
          default:
            url = "null";
            return url;
            break;
        }
      });
    }
      url = employeeType();
      console.log(url); //the url here is null
      //this is working url = "json/administration.json";

      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            //table to load json file
            var table = $('#myTable tbody');
            //loop through the json file
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                console.log(key + " : " + value);
                if (key == "ict-skills") {
                  var ictRow = '<tr class="info"><td colspan="3"><label>ii) ICT Skills</label></td></tr>';
                  table.append(ictRow);
                  $.each(value, function(key1, value1) {
                    for (k in value1) {
                      // console.log( key1 + ':' + k + ':' + value1[k]);
                      var row = '<tr><td>' + value1[k] +
                        '</td><td class="check"><input type="checkbox" class="styled " name="ict[' + k + ']" value="possess"/>' +
                        '</td><td class="check"><input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="ict[' + k + ']" value="train"/></td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                      //console.log(row);
                      table.append(row);
                    }

                  });
                }
              }
            });
```

The html for select is:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Employee ID</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_no">
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Employee Type</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <select class="form-control" name="user" id="user">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="accountant">Accountant</option>
      <option value="admin">Administration</option>
      <option value="clerk">Clerk</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your console.log(option) giving you the correct value at that point? i.e a string of "accountant" etc

Comment: yes @OliverM even the console.log(url) inside the switch statement is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a scope problem, try the below (removed your ajax call for brevity):

```
 var employeeType = function (option) { 
    /* setting currently changed option value to option variable */
    switch (option) {
      case "accountant":
        url = "json/accountant.json";
        return url;
        break;
      case "clerk":
        url = "json/clerk.json";
        return url;
        break;
      case "admin":
        url = "json/administration.json";
        return url;
        break;
      default:
        url = "null";
        return url;
        break;
    }};

  $('#user').change(function(){
    var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    url = employeeType(option);
    alert(url);
  });
```

Edit: Fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/54y171u9/